# How to view Open VPN allocated licenses

Tags: openvpn

I have an Open VPN server running direct access open vpn.

While setting it up i have connected to it from 1 device a few different times and have apparently "used up" my licenses

Is there a way i can check these or revoke them? 
Ive looked through the server settings and cant find any part where my licenses are allocated

*Note* Under Revoke Certificates I only see the Current user setup that i wish to use. 
When connecting as this client, I get a "access server license failure" saying I have used my allocated connections to the server

Comment: You're specifically running the commercial OpenVPN *Access Server* instead of the standalone OpenVPN software, is that right?

Comment: @user1686 Im running an Openvpn server using the free license (2 connections)and I no longer have licenses for clients, yet ive only connected one client. So i was wondering how i can check or remove the existing clients.

I currently have nothing connected to it and its saying im out of licenses